# InDesign, too many line breaks

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

When editing text in inDesign i have a file with hyphenations for the words. But sometimes when the column is narrow there are too many line breaks in a row. E.g. three or four.
Is it possible to reduce the amount of the line breaks by changing the space between words?
Or maybe it is possible to make some text area without line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extensive set of controls for hyphenation. Select the offending paragraph, and go to the Paragraph palette's options (the palette can be found in Window > Type and Tables). In there, select 'Hyphenation...', and set your hyphenation rules as you see fit:

[image: the InDesign dialog box for hyphenation settings]

Even better, you can set these rules to be ingrained into any Paragraph Style you create.

Do realise that some choices will force a lot of hyphenations. Narrow columns with full justification, for example, will require lots of hyphenation in order to avoid large spaces in between some words.

Comment: Thank you! That's what i've been looking for.